# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) with simple async funcs

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

I'm newbie. When I run this code, I catch Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
Help pls, what's wrong?

```
func first() async throws {
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 100)
    print("Potato")
}


func second() async throws {
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1)
    print("Apple")
}

func third(){
    print("Cherry")
}

func MyFunc()  {
    Task {
        print("Banana")
        try await first()
        try await second()
        print("Onion")
    }
    third()
}

MyFunc()
```

Comment: The program should output sequentially: Banana -> Apple -> Potato -> Onion -> Cherry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> When I run this code, I catch Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

The above is insufficient to manifest that problem. It works for me in both an App and a Playground. Where did you have this code? If playground, make sure to

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

If you are still having trouble, please provide more details of precisely the environment and steps you took to produce this crash.

---

You said:

> The program should output sequentially: Banana -> Apple -> Potato -> Onion -> Cherry

A few observations:

- You should not expect “Cherry”, produced by `third` after the `Task` closure, to be at the end. The `Task { … }` runs asynchronously. As soon as it hits a suspension point (aka, an `await`), `third` is free to run.

  Only if you made `MyFunc` [sic] an `async` function, and did an `await` on the `Task` result, would you be guaranteed to see “Cherry” at the end. Or, obviously, you could move `third` inside the `Task` closure, after the `await` of `second`. But, as it is, `third` does not need to wait for the `Task`.
- “Potato” (which is produced by `first`) will always be before “Apple” (produced by `second`). The `MyFunc` has an `try await first()`, which means that it will not attempt to run `second` until the asynchronous tasks of `first` are complete.

  If you did not want `second` to await `first`, you could, for example, use `withThrowingTaskGroup` and then `addTask` those two function calls separately. But as it stands, `second` will not start until `first` finishes.
- When I run this in an app, I see Cherry » Banana » Potato » Apple » Onion. Or in Playground, I see Banana » Cherry » Potato » Apple » Onion. Both of these sequences are perfectly viable responses.

But either way, you should expect neither “Cherry” at the end nor “Apple” before “Potato”.